# CAS SSO for Asp.Net website, attributes not receiving on serviceValidate request

Tags: asp.net, webforms, single-sign-on, cas

I have successfully integrated CAS for our different clients. But this time 'samlValidate' response is not consistently supplying the required attribute. Login is failing randomly because of the missing attribute in the ticket validation response. Sometimes when I clear browser history, it's receiving the attribute in the response.

Expected response:

```
<cas:serviceResponse xmlns:cas='http://www.xxxxx.xxx/tp/cas'>
    <cas:authenticationSuccess>
        <cas:user>xxxxx</cas:user>
        <cas:attributes>    
              <cas:userNumber>1234567</cas:userNumber> 
        </cas:attributes>
    </cas:authenticationSuccess>
</cas:serviceResponse>
```

Response receiving randomly:

```
<cas:serviceResponse xmlns:cas='http://www.xxx.xxx/tp/cas'>
    <cas:authenticationSuccess>
        <cas:user>xxxxxx</cas:user>


    </cas:authenticationSuccess>
</cas:serviceResponse>
```

Please note: We have created a custom code to integrate CAS with our Asp.Net webforms application.

```
string userId = string.Empty;
            // Look for the "ticket=" after the "?" in the URL
            string tkt = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["ticket"];
            // Service url is the url of the Researcher Portal
            string service ="www.xyz.com";            
            string CASHOST="https://cas.xyz.ca:8443/cas"
            // First time through there is no ticket=, so redirect to CAS login
            if (tkt == null || tkt.Length == 0)
            {
                string redir = CASHOST + "login?" +
                  "service=" + service; 
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(redir);
            }
            // Second time (back from CAS) there is a ticket= to validate
            string validateurl = CASHOST + "serviceValidate?" +
              "ticket=" + tkt + 
              "&service=" + service;
            StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(new WebClient().OpenRead(validateurl));
            string resp = Reader.ReadToEnd();

            if (isDebuggingMode)
                sbDebugString.Append("****Response **** \n  " + resp);
            // Some boilerplate to set up the parse.
            NameTable nt = new NameTable();
            XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(nt);
            XmlParserContext context = new XmlParserContext(null, nsmgr, null, XmlSpace.None);
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(resp, XmlNodeType.Element, context);

            string userNumber = null;

            // A very dumb use of XML. Just scan for the "userNumber". If it isn't there, it will return an empty string.
            while (reader.Read())
            {                
                if (reader.IsStartElement())
                {
                    string tag = reader.LocalName;
                    if (isDebuggingMode)
                        sbDebugString.Append("tag : " + tag + "\n");
                    if (tag == "userNumber")
                    {
                        userNumber = reader.ReadString();
                        if (isDebuggingMode)
                            sbDebugString.Append("userNumber : " + userNumber + "\n");
                    }
                }               
            }
```

Where "userNumber" attribute is not receiving always so that login fails randomly.
Please share your thoughts to resolve this issue.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please specify the CAS version.

Comment: CAS 3.5.3, using CAS protocol v2

Answer (score 0):

If your client application is not receiving attributes, you will need to make sure:

1. The client is using a version of CAS protocol that is able to
   release attributes.
2. The client, predicated on #1, is hitting the appropriate endpoint for service ticket validation (i.e. `/p3/serviceValidate`).
3. The CAS server itself is resolving and retrieving attributes correctly.
4. The CAS server is authorized to release attributes to that particular client application inside its service registry.

Starting with CAS Protocol 3:

> Among all features, the most noticeable update between versions 2.0 and 3.0 is the ability to return the authentication/user attributes through the new /p3/serviceValidate endpoint.

You may also find this post useful:
https://apereo.github.io/2017/06/23/cas-protocol-compatibility/

Comment: 1. It's releasing the required attribute sometimes but not always

Comment: 2. How to verify whether the client is hitting the appropriate end point for ticket validation?Could you please assist?

Comment: 3. How to validate this ? We don't have access to the CAS server so if you could guide me to validate 2&3, it would be helpful for me to check with that team.

Comment: 4. I have already checked with the CAS team and they confirmed it